# Getting error on html.action on loading View page with layout page in renderbody of html beginform

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am loading my partial view through html.action on loading on my main view page.

Here is my View code:

**_SectionLayout.cshtml**

```
<html>
<head>
.....
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
         @Html.Action("RenderUpperSection", "UpperSection")//render partial view on load of this master page.
    </div>

  <div class="EditContent">
   @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Section", new RouteValueDictionary() { { "id", Model.SectionId } }))
   {
         @RenderBody()//problem occurs here because here i am loading again my view(SectionIndex.cshtml) with this _SectionLayout.cshtml page.
   }
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My Controller:**UpperSection**

```
 [ChildActionOnly]
        public ActionResult RenderUpperSection()
        {
                return PartialView("_TopSection");
        }
```

Getting error on loading View page with layout page in renderbody of html beginform on html.action

Controller :**Section**

```
 public ActionResult Edit(string id)
 {
     return View("SectionIndex");
 }
```

**SectionIndex.cshtml:**

```
@{

    Layout = _SectionLayout.cshtml
 }

 //Rest of my code.
```

Now when i click on my Edit button then error comes on this line:

`@Html.Action("RenderUpperSection", "UpperSection")//`

> > A public action method 'RenderUpperSection' was not found on controller 'MyProject.Web.Controllers.UpperSectionController'**."

But when first time My **_SectionLayout.cshtml** layout page is loading then this **RenderUpperSection** is calling successfully with rendering of my partial view but when I click on edit method and my **edit method** return **SectionIndex** this view with **_SectionLayout.cshtml** then i get above error on master page.

Same method is calling on first time load of my master page but on click of edit method i got error.

Can anybody tell me what is the problem????

Answer (score 0):

use **RenderPartial** or **RenderAction**

> for ex.
>   @{Html.RenderPartial("RenderUpperSection", "UpperSection");}
>
> or
>   @Html.Partial("RenderUpperSection", "UpperSection")

Comment: Renderuppersection is my actionresult method on my controller and i need to make a call on controller and return partial view that is _TopSection from Renderuppersection  method